# Jquery Check If Input Field Has Changed On Each Keyup

Tags: jquery

I've got this jQuery script which checks to see if an input field has changed, and if it has, it adds a class to an icon (which then changes colour to let the user know they have filled in the field).

```
$('.input-icon input').change(function() {
    $(this).next(".icon").addClass('complete');
});
```

It works but only when the field in question is deselected after the text has been input into it. What I need is for this to run each time a key is pressed and update accordingly.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

```
$('.input-icon input').on('keyup',function() {
    // check if input has something in it
    $(this).next(".icon").addClass('complete');
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyfbM/)